# Изменение значения столбца sql

Tags: sql, база-данных

есть к примеру таблица `user` с полем `age varchar`, хочу изменить значение поля к примеру на int.

 
Есть ли команда для такого действия?

Comment: какая СУБД используется?

Comment: @ArcherGodson mysql

Comment: Изменить тип поля, скорее всего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE user MODIFY age INTEGER
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE user ALTER COLUMN age TYPE integer
```